# Wordpress Author Link 404

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

On a search page I allow the user to click a on the authors name to view all posts by that author. Im trying to create the link to the authors page but I keep getting 404’s. However the admin user works. I have checked the user types and they are set authors (Admin is administrator).

**Code Example**

```
get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_ID());
```

**Result**

This returns "/author/tester/" which looks correct since the admin one "/author/admin/" works. However clicking the link goes to 404.

**Notes**

- This code is executed in a Wordpress loop.
- User type is Author.
- Ideally I would like to use the users nickname/display name not actual.

Comment: Is the author "tester," the author of any posts?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
get_author_posts_url( $author->ID )
```

Also since you're using it within the loop, try without any ID :

```
get_author_posts_url()
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that is the function i’m having problems with. The author id is also a required parameter to that function.